# Error in JSON and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have a class which reads a JSON and sets it into a listview, but I have an error in the logcat when parsing the JSON array making it fail after that the asynctask

I tested the JSON and it's right, I don't know why does it says it's wrong

LogCat:

```
04-29 22:35:55.038    3120-3150/com.ivanmz.forotek.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ivanmz.forotek.app.CaracteristicasProducto$LoadInbox.doInBackground(CaracteristicasProducto.java:85)
at com.ivanmz.forotek.app.CaracteristicasProducto$LoadInbox.doInBackground(CaracteristicasProducto.java:58)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

The Class:

```
public class CaracteristicasProducto extends ListActivity {
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inboxList;

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray inbox = null;

    // Inbox JSON url

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGES = "caracteristicas";
    private static final String TAG_CARA = "caracteristica";
    private static final String TAG_VALOR = "valor";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_producto);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        inboxList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading INBOX in Background Thread
        new LoadInbox().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all INBOX messages by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadInbox extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CaracteristicasProducto.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Inbox ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Inbox JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String id = intent.getExtras().getString("id");
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://www.forotek.net/androidapp/caracteristicasproducto.php?id="+id, "GET",
                    params);
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());

            try {
                inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);
                // looping through All messages
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String cara = c.getString(TAG_CARA);
                    String valor = c.getString(TAG_VALOR);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_CARA, cara);
                    map.put(TAG_VALOR, valor);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    inboxList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            CaracteristicasProducto.this, inboxList,
                            R.layout.list_caracteristica_producto, new String[] {TAG_CARA, TAG_VALOR},
                            new int[] {R.id.from, R.id.subject});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Line 85 of CaracteristicasProducto.java

Comment: can you show implementation of `JSONParser` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your Json in http://jsonlint.com/ .

It has missing a "," COMMA in character 1526 :

...{"caracteristica":"Imagen","valor":"http://www.gizmochina.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/iNew-V3-01.jpg"**}{**"caracteristica":"Pulgadas","valor":"5"},{...

should be:

...{"caracteristica":"Imagen","valor":"http://www.gizmochina.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/iNew-V3-01.jpg"**},{**"caracteristica":"Pulgadas","valor":"5"},{...